# Поведение typeid

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

Почему нельзя завязываться на имя класса в кросс-платформенном коде? При получении имени класса через оператор `typeid`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На имя класса в `typeid` нельзя завязываться ни в каком коде. Спецификация стандартной библиотеки не дает никаких гарантий на поведение метода `std::type_info::name()`: она не гарантирует наличия какого-либо осмысленного или практически полезного имени класса. Методы `std::type_info::name()` могут просто возвращать `"Вася"` для всех типов или вообще возвращать нестабильное значение от запуска к запуску одной и той же программы.

Comment: Не знаю как на win32 - но на Linux type_info вообще чистая энтропия для кастомных типов)

Answer (score 3):

typeid(this).name" на gcc и на msvc дает разный вывод

на msvc: "class Foo *"

на gcc:     "P4Foo"

Comment: typeid(*this).name": 
на msvc: "class Foo" 
на gcc: "12Foo"